# Cannot get AdMobs to display over map

Tags: android, xml, google-maps, admob

I have followed this tutorial: [AdMob Code](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals#play)

But I cannot get the banner to display (not even the common XML adSize error that I have seen a lot of online:

This is the code in my main_activity:

```
private AdView adView;
    private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    GoogleMap mMap;
    LatLng myposition;
    Marker marker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Create an ad.
        adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

        //Add the AdView to the view hierarchy.The view will have no size
        //Until the ad is loaded.
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lyout);
        layout.addView(adView);

        //Create an ad request. Check kogcat output for the hashed device ID to
        //get test ads on a physical device.
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        .addTestDevice("MY_DEVICE_ID")
        .build();

        //Start loading the ad in the background.
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

}

And this is my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/lyout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
     >


<fragment xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/the_map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    map:cameraTilt="45"
    map:cameraZoom="15"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

At first my layout file was only:

```
 <fragment xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:id="@+id/the_map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        map:cameraTilt="45"
        map:cameraZoom="15"
        />
```

EDIT: LogCat removed as working

But that wasn't working either. How do I get these ads to display?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load the banner ad like below from the xml layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             ads:adUnitId="MY_AD_UNIT_ID"
             ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR"
             ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
             ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
    <fragment xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
             android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
             android:id="@+id/the_map"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             map:cameraTilt="45"
             map:cameraZoom="15" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Note: if you have generated your appId just recently in admob account then may be there will be no advertise to display for your id to Admob engine so wait for a while and then try again. May be that will also work.

Hope it will help you..

Comment: Rushabh - I have implemented above, and now I get a banner area above my map, but I am now getting an error in that saying: Required XML attribute "adSize" was missing. But I have that already set. I got my appId yesterday from google so I thought i t should be working by now? Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/master/admob/banner-xml

Comment: Checkout the above example.. and yes your app id should work now. also keep checking your log while loading app because sometimes ad request can be successfully loaded but adEngine does not give you the ad to display. So all these info you will find in log..

Comment: Ok thank you, I will check out the example, and pay extra attention to the LogCat